# How to forward a local port to remote server using sockets in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets, portforwarding, openvpn

I am working on a dart code to run on android devices. The project needs to bind a socket on local port (for example 2360) and then forward all sent and received data to another remote socket that connects to a remote server.

```
final serverSocket = await ServerSocket.bind(
    "127.0.0.1", 2360,
    shared: true);
await for (var clientSocket in serverSocket) {
  print(
      'Accepted connection from ${clientSocket.remoteAddress.address}:${clientSocket.remotePort}');

  clientSocket.setOption(SocketOption.tcpNoDelay, true);
  Socket fSocket = await SecureSocket.connect(
      'remote.server.com', 5051,
      context: context);
  clientSocket.listen(
    (event) {
      fSocket.add(event.toList());
    },
    onError: (error) {
      print(error);
      clientSocket.close();
    },
    onDone: () {
      print('Local left');
      clientSocket.close();
    },
  );
  fSocket.setOption(SocketOption.tcpNoDelay, true);
  fSocket.listen(
        (event) {
      clientSocket.add(event.toList());
    },
    onError: (error) {
      print(error);
      fSocket?.close();
    },
    onDone: () {
      print('Foreign left');
      fSocket?.close();
    },
  );
}
```

I've tried to connect to an OpenVPN server through this code and it connects but disconnects suddenly after a while.